# How comes the lifetime of a local variable inside a function be extended?

Tags: variables, constructor, local, move

See the code below. v1 is local variable inside a function. Accordingly, after leaving this fucntion, this variable should be killed. Thus, the move constructor should run into problem in the main function. But actually the outcome is the opposite. In the main function, I can see the contents of v1.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void my_fn(vector<vector<int>> & v) {
    vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
    v.push_back(move(v1));
    cout << " " << endl;
}

int main(){
    vector<vector<int>>  v;
    my_fn(v);
    for(const auto & e:v)
        for (const auto e1: e)
            cout << e1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move the contents of `v1` into `v`, `v1` is not yet destroyed because that happens right before the closing bracket of the function `my_fn`. As a result, the contents of `v1` are pushed into `v` which is taken by reference. The scope of `v1` is not extended but its content is just copied.

Comment: My intuition is similar as yours. But strictly, the storage space for v1 is on the stack, right? After leaving the function, this space should be reclaimed, right?

Comment: Well, the data members of v1 are indeed on the stack but the array members are stored on the heap because it is a vector and not an array. The space held by v1 on the heap and on the stack is reclaimed after being copied by the push_back and the move into memory owned by v.

Comment: also note that here I used a move constructor.

Comment: That doesn’t change anything since v can’t steel v1’s memory since you are appending v1’s elements to v.

Comment: So new memory will always have to allocated since v has to contain both it’s elements and v1’s elements.

Comment: Are you satisfied with my answer? I would like to recommend the following CppCon talk on r-value semantics https://youtu.be/St0MNEU5b0o.

Comment: Many Thanks! So here using std::move does not make any sense?

Comment: Yes exactly! Could you please mark the question as answered than?